# Not putting variable in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my snippet of PHP I am currently using to put a randomly generator string in a row, but it is not working. I need $actc to go into the actc field of the row, but it is not actually doing that, it stays 0.

```
$chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"; 
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$i = 0;
$actc = '' ;
while ($i <= 11) {
$num = rand() % 33;
$tmpc = substr($chars, $num, 1);
$actc = $actc . $tmpc;
$i++;
}
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, pass, email, ip, actc)
            VALUES ('".$nl."', '".$pw."', '".$email."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$actc."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

My table structure exported in SQL:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `actc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4531 ;
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a `string` type value into an `int(11)` type column. MySQL will try and parse your `string` but if it does not start with a digit, you will just get `0`.

Comment: Using 32 will give you a *slightly* better random distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're initializing $actc as a string, but the column type in mysql is an int.  You can't insert a non-Int into an Int column.

Also you are quoting $actc as thought it were a string in your insert statement.  Ints are not quoted in mysql insert statements.

Comment: Thanks. That's a stupid mistake of me, must've originally planned to only use numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`actc` is an `INT` field, so only numeric values are accepted. It looks like your code can generate any combination of letters and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a `string` type value into an `int(11)` type column. MySQL will try and parse your `string` but if it does not start with a digit, you will just get `0`.

Just change the column to a `varchar`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  [...]
  `actc` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are storing a value having alphanumeric characters into a column specified as int(11) ..!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  **`actc` varchar(11) NOT NULL,**
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4531 ;
```